# How to extract the WAV tracks from Blu-ray or DVD-Audio discs?

Tags: dvd, music, ripping, blu-ray, wav

I would like to find a way to rip the WAV tracks (LPCM 2.0, 192kHz, 24-bit) from a [Blu-ray Audio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu-ray_Disc#Audio) or a [DVD-Audio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-Audio) disc using Linux. (Once extracted, it should then be a breeze to encode the audio tracks into FLAC.)

Taking the [TrondheimSolistene: Divertimenti](http://www.blu-ray.com/movies/TrondheimSolistene-Divertimenti-Blu-ray/1097/#Review) Blu-ray disc as an example, how do you extract the WAV tracks?

Answer (score 2):

`ffmpeg` is your friend...

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/FFmpeg_-_Extract_Blu-Ray_Audio

Make sure you got the right version installed, because there are some differences between versions.

Answer (score 0):

I found two tools that can help with the job.

[ACE-Encode](http://joelbassett.github.io/ace-encode/) is a FOSS script:

> ACE-Encode was born from the need convert a whole CD/DVD/BluRay library (450+) into music & movie files readable on a Home Theater PC (HTPC).
>
> ACE-Encode works by automatically ripping an inserted CD/DVD/BluRay to a folder

To enable automatic CD/DVD/BluRay ripping:

> Step 4 takes into account that you have ABCDE, DVDBackup, MakeMKV & HandBrake installed and working correctly. For help installing any of the above, please see the INSTALLATION section for each extension.

---

Another tool is [MakeMKV](http://www.makemkv.com/). It is not FOSS and reportedly costs $50. The Beta version is usually free, but this could change anytime.

For Ubuntu Linux users you can install MakeMKV from the [ppa:heyarje/makemkv-beta](https://launchpad.net/%7Eheyarje/+archive/ubuntu/makemkv-beta) PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:heyarje/makemkv-beta
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install makemkv-bin makemkv-oss
```

Usually all features of MakeMKV are free while the program is in beta. You may purchase the full activation key if you like the program and want to show your support, but you also may use the temporary beta key. Check the PPA page for the current beta key.